# In htdocs htaccess file not found

Tags: htdocs

where the htaccess file stored in htdocs folder.
I try find it in my development server but i did not find it.

Whenever i try to type url which is not valid it is redirect to home page of site.
I am not able to find out where setting will be stored.

Thanks

Comment: this is mostly done via the config of your hosting company. Simply create your own .htaccess file and place it in your htdocs?

Comment: please specify how do you access to your server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what OS you use, Linux will recognize the `.htaccess` file as hidden Windows doesn't.

The `.htaccess` file **could** be in the root folder of your webserver (htdocs for example).
But it doesn't need to be there by default. If it is not in there by default you can just create one your self

Answer (score 0):

Are your trying to find with server machine by connect with FTP via Filezilla.

If filezilla means you can't see the htdocs file, instead of that you can connect with Winscp means you can find the .htaccess file